# Error use StingRay Grid on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, c, mfc, rogue-wave, stingray

I use rogue wave stingray [Rogue-Wave](https://www.roguewave.com/products-services/stingray) to create grid. I use `CGXGridView` class.

I followed this tutorial [https://docs.roguewave.com/stingray/11/html/ogug/7.html](https://docs.roguewave.com/stingray/11/html/ogug/). But when debug in line `GXInit()`, show this error:

> Debug Assertion Failed
>
> Program: F:\Data\Exercise\FirstGrid.exe File:
>   \dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxwin1.inl
>   Line: 21
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the visual c++ documentation on asserts
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

With Visual Studio 2010 it runs successfully, but Visual Studio 2013 shows the  error above. How do I fix it so that StingRay can run on Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: The is a line information in the assertion missing. Please use the debugger. Tell aus, what ASSERT fails. Usually an ASSERT tells you that a condition that is required for the functionality of a control is not met. In a lot of cases for this inl code section the window is simply not created.

Comment: I notice you have tagged it c++ and c. It must be one or the other. I assume c++ since you are tagged mfc.

Comment: *"Press Retry to debug the application"* - Did you? What insights did you gather from doing so?

Comment: @IInspectable, When I Press Retry to debug the application, show message "FirstGrid.exe has triggered a breakpoint". 

I clicked continue button, then show thiess error :

Debug Assertion Failed

Program: F:\Data\Exercise\FirstGrid.exe File: \dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxwin1.inl
Line: 24

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the visual c++ documentation on asserts

(Press Retry to debug the application)

Comment: The debugger takes you straight to the line of code that failed the assertion. That should give you a good hint as to which (pre-)condition or invariant was violated.